# How to exclude folder from Typewriter code generation

Tags: typewriter

I'm using the settings below to include project "Soft.Data" in my Typewriter code generation.

**But how do I exclude a specific folder (e.g. "ViewModels") from the code generation?**

```
Template(Settings settings)
{
    settings.IncludeProject("Soft.Data");
    settings.OutputFilenameFactory = file => 
    {
        return $"{file.Name.Replace("ViewModel", "GenViewModel").Replace(".cs", ".ts")}";
    };        
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a lambda filter in your template to exclude a namespace.

```
${
    Template(Settings settings)
    {
        settings.IncludeProject("Soft.Data");
        settings.OutputFilenameFactory = file => 
        {
            return $"{file.Name.Replace("ViewModel", "GenViewModel").Replace(".cs", ".ts")}";
        };        
    }
}
$Classes(c => c.Namespace != "Soft.Data.ViewModels")[
...
]
```